# How to retrieve a lambda from a std::vector of std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, vector, lambda, shared-ptr

Following peace of code is not working:

```
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    
    std::function<int()>      dummy1 = []() { return -3; };
    std::function<unsigned()> dummy2 = []() { return 33333; };

    auto test1 = std::make_shared<std::function<int()>>(dummy1);
    auto test2 = std::make_shared<std::function<unsigned()>>(dummy2);

    std::cout << "Final 1: " << (*test1)() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Final 2: " << (*test2)() << "\n";

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<void>> ptr;

    ptr.push_back(test1);
    ptr.push_back(test2);

    // Does not work
    std::cout << "Final 3: " << (*ptr[0])() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

https://onlinegdb.com/vJZ2q9ctk

How to define a std::vector to lambdas with different return values?

**The bigger picture**

The plan is to have in a concrete implementation a central data structure (for monitoring) which queries different getters in different modules with different return types.

The querying of the data shall take place on a regular base calling all the getters.

It should be possible to configure the getters at compile time.

To maintain a generic approach and only rely on a config.h file the vector should be formed as generic as possible (but avoiding std::any because of this seems a bit dubious for me)

Comment: The solution is to create a template class to store the function, inherit it from a non-template base, then store `std::shared_ptr<MyBase>` and `dynamic_cast` before use. But 99% of the time, when this gets asked, the person doesn't actually need to store the functions in a single vector, and would be better off with separate vectors per function type. Can you elaborate why you need this?

Comment: What is the original and underlying problem you need to solve? Why do you need anonymous pointers to different functions? How would that solve the original problem? Perhaps there are other possible solutions? Please ask about that original problem directly, showing your solution to help us understand how you think about it and how it can be solved. Right now your question is too much of an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: C++ is statically typed language, so the compiler needs to know what type `(*ptr[0])()` evaluates to at compile-time. Why do you need to return a value whose type you do not know? You cannot do anything with it - what if it is not printable? You could use `std::variant` of functions instead of `void` in the vector if you have a fixed amount of types.

Comment: Related(might give more context): [Template of std::function for lambdas with different return types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77517142/template-of-stdfunction-for-lambdas-with-different-return-types)

Comment: Also, why are you using `printf` in a C++ program? Just stay with c++ and the modern features provided by it and avoid using C features like `printf`, built in arrays etc.

Comment: Did you already compare the footprint of printf vs cout?

Comment: This feels like you try to solve a design-problem in code, which will seldom work out well. As a possible quick-fix workaround: Different containers, one for each return-type? One function processes all containers (by using a templated function for the actual processing). I assume you have some way to, at run-time, know what return-type the modules will have? Otherwise I fear it might be time to go back to the requirements, analysis and design, to fix it where it should be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to define a std::vector to lambdas with different return values?

Impossible to implement in a simple useful way.

Imagine it is possible. Then I add the following two lambdas into your vector:

```cpp
struct Foo {};
struct Bar {};

ptr.push_back([]() { return Foo{}; });
ptr.push_back([]() { return Bar{}; });
```

You cannot write code that uses `ptr` that works both for `struct Foo` and `struct Bar` unless you assume *something* about them. Hence, you are actually not talking about *arbitrary* types. You talk about *some restricted subset of types*.

Maybe you want types that can be `<<`ed. Maybe you have some list of types that can happen in your config (e.g. only `std::string`, `int` and `double`) and depending on the config key the expected type is different.

But the compiler has no way of knowing that. Moreover, you cannot prove to the compiler that the return type depends on the key, it's called "dependent types" and is more or less non-existent in C++ unless you do template metaprogramming and compile-time evaluation shenanigans. The compiler has to generate code that works *for all possible types that can happen*. All elements of `std::vector` have the same time in compile time. Hence, if you call them, the returned type is the same. But you can then do some run-time calculations to convert that returned type to some specific type of your choice.

In your specific case, I suggest `std::variant<int, unsigned>`. Add all other types that can happen in the config.

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <variant>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    
    std::function<int()>      dummy1 = []() { return -3; };
    std::function<unsigned()> dummy2 = []() { return 33333; };

    auto test1 = std::make_shared<std::function<std::variant<int, unsigned>()>>(dummy1);
    auto test2 = std::make_shared<std::function<std::variant<int, unsigned>()>>(dummy2);

    std::cout << "Final 1: " << std::get<int>((*test1)()) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Final 2: " << std::get<unsigned>((*test2)()) << "\n";

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::function<std::variant<int, unsigned>()>>> ptr;

    ptr.push_back(test1);
    ptr.push_back(test2);

    std::cout << "Final 3: " << std::get<int>((*ptr[0])()) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Note that *you should know in advance* what is the returned type of each element of vector. If you guess incorrectly, `std::get` throws `std::bad_variant_access`. Or you can ask via `.index()` or pass a generic lambda via `.visit()`.

Comment: Thank you @yeputons. I used your snippet and it works pretty well.